# Doesn't void return value in this instance?

Tags: c#

```
void AddOne(int x){
        x += 1;
}
```

Doesn't this return the value of x+1 to the AddOne method?
If so, why is then a void?

Comment: The question is hard to answer because evidently there is something you don't understand, but it is really unclear what it is that you don't understand. Void methods return no value, so the answer to your first question is "no", and the answer to the second question is "see the answer to the first question". Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Let me try to help you clarify the question.  Consider this: `void AddOne(int x) { int t = x + 1; x = t; }`  That program fragment is *the same* as your program fragment. Does the program fragment I just gave you *return a value*? If you believe that it does, can you say *why* you believe that?

Comment: This method increments the parameter `x` by 1, but never returns it. Since `int` isn't a reference type, this has no effect outside of the method. In other words, this method is only producing some CO₂, nothing else. (Don't show it Greta Thunberg!)

Comment: Why do you think that this *would* return anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it increments `x` by 1 but returns nothing.

Try calling:

```
int value = AddOne(1);
```

It won't compile.

You would need to declare a return type i.e. `int` and use the `return` keyword.

```
int AddOne(int x)
{
    return x += 1;
}
```

Although you are probably getting confused with the `+=` operator, which increments an existing variable in place, but has nothing to do with returning a value.

The above is effectively the same as:

```
int AddOne(int x)
{
    x += 1;
    return x;
}
```

You would be better to do the following to avoid confusion:

```
int AddOne(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}
```